# Conditional variance of joint density.

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

Joint density for X and Y is

$f(x,y)=2e^{-x-2y} \ \ \ \ \ \ $for$ \ \ \ x>0,y>0 $

$0$ otherwise

Calculate the variance of $Y$ given that $X>3$ and $Y>3$

Can we use this formula somehow here $V(Y)=E(V(X|Y))+V(E(X|Y))$?

I thought that because joint density seems like product of two exponential distributions one can be conditional density and other can be marginal. Am i think totally wrong ? Bad way to deal this problem i guess. When i tried to solve this it was very laborious.

Comment: Good observation. The first thing to simplify the matter is to observe that $X, Y$ are independent and $Y$ indeed has a marginal exponential distribution. Next you need to deal with the variance of a truncated exponential $Var[Y|Y > 3]$, by computing the pdf first.

Comment: @BGM Could you please give me a thorough solution for this problem ?I am not able to pick up from the hints you gave me or elaborate little bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are obviously independent so we can calculate the variance of $Y|x>3,Y>3$ easily. First note that $$Y|x>3,Y>3=Y|Y>3$$ so the variance is$$Var[Y|Y>3]=E[Y^2|Y>3]-E^2[Y|Y>3]$$also knowing $Pr(Y>3)=e^{-6}$ we have: $$E[Y^2|Y>3]=\dfrac{1}{e^{-6}}\int_{3}^{\infty}2y^2e^{-2y}dy=\dfrac{25}{2}$$and $$E[Y|Y>3]=\dfrac{1}{e^{-6}}\int_{3}^{\infty}2ye^{-2y}dy=\dfrac{7}{2}$$therefore$$Var[Y|Y>3]=\dfrac{25}{2}-\dfrac{49}{4}=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Can you tell me how this $Y|x>3,Y>3$ converted to $Y|Y>3$ ?

Comment: Since of independence between $X$ and $Y$ we can calculate the statistics of any of them regardless of that of the other one.

Comment: Oh god i totally forgot independence silly me . Anyways thank you .

Comment: It is OK.......Good luck!

Comment: You may miss the normalizing constant $1/\Pr\{Y > 3\}$ for the truncated pdf.

Comment: Very useful comment...... Thank you!

Comment: @BGM You should write answer too. Give some helpful tips. This is not my homework believe me i am learning things.